# Why do I receive a syntax error when using "and" to declare an array in PyThon?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am learning scipy and more specifically Numpy. I wrote the following code after properly declaring an array and received the indicated error message. Would like to know why

```
data = np.sin(np.arange(20)).reshape(5,4)
and = data.argmax(axis=1)
```

Error:

```
File "<stdin>", line 1
and = data.argmax(axis = 1)
  ^
  SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Oh, wait, there was actually a line break there, but because you didn't code-format your code (formatting is crucial!), your code shows up as one line and gives a very different impression of what you were trying to do.

Comment: I am sorry. Did not realize the question was to post this way. A new lesson learned.   Thanks.

Comment: Don't use `and` as a variable name, it's a reserved keyword in Python

Answer (score 2):

`and` is a keyword in Python, used for boolean conjunction. You can't name your variables `and`; pick a different name.

Answer (score 1):

`and` is a logical operator in Python, so you cannot assign something to it.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use reserved words as your variables. Pick another name like and1 maybe

Answer (score 0):

`and` is a Logical Operator use something along the sorts of `_and` instead